# Problema ao criar relacionamento com classe de usuario (IdentityUser) usando IdentityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Quando crio qualquer relacionamento com a minha classe usuario:

```
 namespace Modelo.Cadastro
{
    public class Usuario : IdentityUser
    {
        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "O nome de usuário deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome do usuário")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        //public virtual ICollection<Parecer> Pareceres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Eu recebo o seguinte erro quando o EntityFramework efetua tentativa de criar o banco: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> Projeto02.Persistencia.Contexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType
>   'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined
>
> Projeto02.Persistencia.Contexts.IdentityUserRole: EntityType
>   'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined.

Eu já verifiquei várias soluções, inclusive incluir as seguintes linhas no meu context:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

ou ainda mapear as keys para as classes também:

```
public class IdentityDbContextAplicacao : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
    {
        public IdentityDbContextAplicacao() : base("IdentityDb")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id).Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => new { u.UserId, u.LoginProvider, u.ProviderKey });
        }

        static IdentityDbContextAplicacao()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDbContextAplicacao> (new IdentityDbInit());
        }
        public static IdentityDbContextAplicacao Create()
        {
            return new IdentityDbContextAplicacao();
        }

        public class IdentityDbInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<IdentityDbContextAplicacao>
        {
        }
    }
```

e nada funciona! Alguma outra saída?

Comment: Pode [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar o código de `IdentityUserLogin`?

Comment: Na verdade não implementei nada para 'IdentityUserLogin', apenas tentei uma solução mas que não funcionou em meu caso

Comment: Como assim "não implementou nada"? Você criou uma classe vazia?

Comment: Desculpe se me expressei mal, mas apenas usei esta classe do `IdentityFramework` para ver se solucionava meu problemas, não re-implementei a classe

Comment: Você tem dois contextos criados na aplicação?

Comment: Sim, um estou usando para os outro modelos e um para o Identity

Answer (score 1):

Como sua classe herda de `IdentityUser` a chave primária desse objeto é definida no método `OnModelCreating` da classe [IdentityDbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext.aspx).

E ao que parece pelo erro o seu contexto está derivando de `DbContext`.

Você pode ver uma resposta mais detalhada em inglês nesta [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28532180/36147).

Comment: vappolinario, editei minha pergunta e inseri a minha classe que herda do `IdentityDbContext<Usuario>`, ainda não compreendi a solução

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente não esta achando a chave primaria na classe `IdentityUserLogin`. Acima do Id coloca `[Key]` e importa a `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Onde ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```